# Is it possible to paste local images in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am wondering if this is possible in Google Sheets.

I am trying to create a visual database of products in the form of a shared spreadsheet. The images cannot be online for privacy and trade secret reasons.

So far I have been using Apple Numbers which allows this through drag and drop or copy paste functions.

This is more or less what it should look like:

[image]

I haven't found recent or clear explanations about this when I searched.

Comment: This question looks to be primarily opinion based but also looks like a requirement for recommendations than a question looking for help about how to use the related web app. Please edit your question and add, add what you tried.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, what do you believe the "opinion" is? At first I called the question "can one paste a local photo in Google Sheets" but I have a couple more requirements. I couldn't find answers to how to do that when I looked online

Comment: "Is X appropriate for Y?" is an primarily opinion based because different users could give contradictory answers and each of them could be correct answers depending on the considerations that each answer made.

Comment: I'm not sure how the answers to the 2-3 requirements I have could be opinion-based and not pure and simple data. Otherwise rather than closing it maybe move it to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based, but I do think it's very broad.  I think the best approach would be to try it and see, then return to ask a more specific question.  It's not really appropriate for Software Recs, because it's not asking for a recommendation.  You are certainly welcome to post it wherever you think it will be answered, but I will not migrate it there.

Comment: Thank you! I will refine the question soon or divide it into several questions.

Comment: I reworded and simplified the question, please reopen or comment if that's not good still, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The term used on the Google Docs Editors Help Center are "insert" and "add".

From [Insert or delete images or videos](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447?hl=en):

> #### Add an image
>
> 1. Open a document, spreadsheet, or presentation in Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides.
> 2. Click **Insert** and then **Image**.
> 3. Select from the following options:
>
>    - **Upload:** Choose an image from your computer and click **Open**.
>    - **Take a snapshot:** Use your webcam and click **Take a snapshot**.
>    - **By URL:** Paste the URL of an image from the web and click **Select**.
>    - **Your albums:** Choose an image from one of your photos albums stored on the web and click **Select**.
>    - **Google Drive:** Choose an image stored in Google Drive and click **Select**.
>    - **Search:** Choose an image from the stock photography archive, or the Google and Life archives, and click **Select**.
> 4. Your image will be added to your file.